# Tridion Integration Framework failed to install default .net connector

Tags: sites-9.5, integration, framework

I create new default .net connector using this page for Sites 9.5:
https://docs.rws.com/972952/741535/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-connector-reference/creating-a-connector-using-the-template-for--net

However, when I try to run it, I get the following exception in the logs, and that is the only exception.

```
2024-03-18 21:02:23,567 ERROR [Thread-6] RemotingContext - Fatal error in remoting context.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.sdl.tridion.remoting.core.internal.launcher.NetCoreLauncher.escapeSpace(NetCoreLauncher.java:127)
    at com.sdl.tridion.remoting.core.internal.launcher.NetCoreLauncher.getCommands(NetCoreLauncher.java:44)
    at com.sdl.tridion.remoting.core.internal.launcher.Launcher.runLauncherProcess(Launcher.java:44)
    at com.sdl.tridion.remoting.core.internal.RemotingContext.initializeChannelInitiatorConnection(RemotingContext.java:462)
    at com.sdl.tridion.remoting.core.internal.RemotingContext.run(RemotingContext.java:327)
    at com.sdl.tridion.remoting.core.RemotingChannel.run(RemotingChannel.java:244)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

On my machine, I have installed .net core 3.1 installed:

[image]

**Just as a note, connector works ok ON CM SIDE, it fails only on Delivery SIDE.**

Also, my configuration is as follows:

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "CConnector": {
      "configuration": {
        "pageSize": 3
      }
    }
  },
  "sitesCm": {
    "isEnabled": true,
    "CConnector": {
      "namespaces": {
        "cel": {
          "displayName": "test",
          "stubFolders": [ "tcm:11-256-2" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "staging": {
    "isEnabled": true,
    "CConnector": {
      "namespaces": {
        "cel": {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding an answer so that it can be more visible. @Rick was right to point me to the correct direction. The problem was visible when file path to the .netcore launcher (which resides in the TIF content extension) **had empty spaces.**

For example:

```
C:\Tridion Delivery\Content Service\.....
```

This has to be:

```
C:\TridionDelivery\ContentService\.....
```

Which is mental.
Only when this was changed, did the code start working correctly.
Hopefully, it helps someone else.

Comment: Really?! That sound like a bug worth reporting with RWS Customer Support. Have you tried the work-around using environment variables, e.g. `Tridion.Remoting.Launcher.BasePath` ?

Comment: oh yes, it happens when microservices are on windows.

Comment: Are you sure it was the spaces and not the parenthesis in the path?

Comment: yes, i tested with spaces, and it still is not working. only when I completely remove the spaces, it starts working

Answer (score 2):

That's strange. Looking at the Stack Trace in the error message, it seems there is a problem with resolving the path of the TIF .NET Core Launcher, yielding a `null` path which then causes the `NullPointerException` later on.

The code which determines the path is as follows:

```
private String getLauncherFilePath() {
    String launcherPath = null;
    try {
        launcherPath = super.getLauncherPath();
    }
    catch (RemotingInfrastructureException e) {}
    if (launcherPath == null) {
        return System.getProperty("Tridion.Remoting.NetCoreLauncherPath");
    }
    return launcherPath + File.separator + LAUNCHER_NETCORE_FILENAME;
}

protected String super.getLauncherPath() {
    String launcherPath = System.getProperty("Tridion.Remoting.Launcher.BasePath");
    if (launcherPath == null) {
        File jarLocation = new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile());
        launcherPath = jarLocation.getParent();
    }
    return getAbsolutePath(launcherPath + File.separator + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

The only way I see that you can get `null` out of this method is that a `RemotingInfrastructureException` occurred and that `System.getProperty("Tridion.Remoting.NetCoreLauncherPath")` is also `null` (i.e. no environment variable with that name is defined).

Frankly, I don't see yet how a `RemotingInfrastructureException` could occur in the `super.getLauncherPath()` implementation, but I hope the code gives you some more background in the resolving logic and may lead to the root cause (or a work-around, e.g. setting some of these environment variables)